# Can I tell my boss I'm leaving after he travelled to meet me?

Tags: ethics, resignation

I'm currently working in Spain for a global company and I want to leave. Another company wants to give me the job I applied for and I will receive the offer in the coming days. My future boss told me to not resign until we have an agreement, but I'm pretty sure I'll accept the job.

My current boss who is in America right now plans to fly to Spain to meet me, as he does every year to talk about objectives and trainings. I feel bad because I don't want to let him travel so far and then tell him I'm leaving. But I don't want to tell him (or anyone else) that I'm leaving before I'm officially leaving.

What should I do?

Comment: Is he flying over, just to meet you? Or might he have a holiday/other meetings planed anyway? Seems very unlikely to me a boss would fly across the ocean just to meet one employee. Seems rather inefficient.

Comment: Your boss is flying from America to Spain *only* to meet you? I find that rather hard to believe. Are you sure he isn't coming in for a much bigger business trip with many more events in the agenda?

Comment: @MaskedMan My company flies people out across the world for single one-off meetings relatively regularly. I'm sure the boss would make extra plans to make it a productive trip - but it wouldn't seem impossible for this meeting to be the primary driver of the trip.

Comment: Do you foresee any way that your boss could change your mind? Also, it's a little late now, but you typically shouldn't put in notice until *after* you have received an offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic rule is don't tell anyone that you are going to resign until you have the offer, decided that it is acceptable and have told your new employer.  If you tell your present employer that you are going to resign and that your manager should not come over to see you before the offer is in then what do you do when the offer either does not materialise or does not live up to your expectations.  You have burned bridges at your current job and have nowhere to go.

Let him come over.  If the offer comes in before the date of the meeting you can resign and he can cancel his travel plans if that is necessary.

Until you are certain that you are going to leave you must just keep up the pretence that you will work there until you retire.

Answer (score 4):

Propose him to have a skype call instead. Tell him you wouldn't feel ok for him to invest so much time and effort into this meeting.

But then it's his decision whether he's coming or not and if he's decided there's not much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an offer yet, and you haven't resigned. It's potentially possible that neither of those things will happen, so continue as normal until they do. Don't change your bosses plans for him.